# Put Date in Specific Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I found the following code in another post here to add a date after an edit but it places it in an offset column, I would like the date in Column 8 if column 3 or 4 has been edited. 
What do I change?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if ([3,4].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- then try **`e.range.offset(0, 7)`**

  ```
  function onEdit(e) {
   if ([3,4].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
   e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(new Date());
   }
  }
  ```
- to have dates only in one column try like this:

  ```
  function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
    "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    nextCell.setValue(newDate);
  }
  if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
    var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
    "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
  }}}
  ```

  - **`"Sheet1"`** = sheet name
  - **`r.getColumn() == 3`** = column **C** / 3rd column
  - **`r.offset(0, 7)`** = offset timestamp 7 columns to the right on the same row eg column **H**
  - **`"GMT+8"`** = timezone
  - **`"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`** = date and time format

    ---
- alternative (untested):

  ```
  function onEdit(e) { 
   if ([3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) { 
   e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(new Date()); } 
   if ([4].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) { 
   e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(new Date()); } }
  ```

Comment: I have tried that, by using offset it offsets a change from the original column number so depending which column changes it puts the date in different columns, I want a single specific column for a change in either 3 or 4

Comment: @FredS answer updated

Comment: For some reason that didnt work for me, maybe due to the sheet name, but I did follow your example and came up with the following that does seem to work.

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
 if ([3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
 e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(new Date());
 }
 if ([4].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
 e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(new Date());
 }
}

Comment: @FredS glad to hear that. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers